# How to create a new data source in saiku to connect to AWS athena

Tags: amazon-athena, saiku

I am trying to connect from Saiku to AWS athena. I wasnt able to connect.
Create Data Source
Name:
Athena

Connection Type:
URL:
jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443

Schema:
Jdbc Driver: 
com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver

Username: 
AKIAILFU5JS4XB4RTBAQ

Password:
••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

Security: None

These are my settings , But nothing works.

Any help ..?

Answer (score 0):

You may integrate AWS Athena with Saiku through JNDI. 
While creating a database connection in Saiku, select the following options:

**Database type**: Generic database
**Access**: JNDI
**JNDI name**: aws (let's say)

[Screenshot of create database window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh2Ti.jpg)

You need to edit your bi-server/tomcat/conf/context.xml file to make this work. Add following in **context.xml** file within the context tag:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/aws" 
                auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" 
                username="your_aws_key" 
                password="your_aws_secret_key" 
                driverClassName="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver"
                url="jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443"
                connectionProperties='s3_staging_dir=s3://your_s3_staging_directory/'
        />
```

Save it. Don't forget to add the Athena driver to your tomcat classpath in the tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/lib folder, if not already present. 

Restart your bi-server after this and the connection should work.

Reference link:
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0H0/Specify_Data_Connections_for_the_Pentaho_Server/Set_Up_JNDI_Connections_for_the_Pentaho_Server

Comment: Hello karu, I just posted my query as an answer. Please check. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello karu, I just posted my query as an answer. Please check. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, you need to create the connection in Saiku for these settings to work. I have added the screenshot of create database connection window I am referring to. It might be that your pentaho/saiku version is different. Try to look for this option.

Comment: Hello, I dont see such connection type settings in the saiku UI :( and I am using latest saiku version community edition .

Comment: I hope you have added the Athena driver to tomcat classpath. You could place the jar in tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/lib and restart saiku server to see if it works through your version's UI.